# awk command does not work properly when assigning output to variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, quoting

I'm trying to convert space to underscore in a file name, my script is 
like below.

```
old_file=/home/somedir/otherdir/foobar 20170919.csv
new_file="$(basename "$old_file")" | awk 'gsub(" ","_")'
```

This script works fine when I use with `echo` command,

```
echo "$(basename "$old_file")" | awk 'gsub(" ","_")'
```

but when it comes to assigning the output to variables, it doesn't work...

Does anybody know the idea?

Comment: doesnt work in this way ? x=$(echo "$(basename "$old_file")" | awk 'gsub(" ","_")') echo $x

Comment: Also for `Awk` to work 1. enclose the actions within `{..}` i.e. as `.. | awk '{gsub(" ","_")}'` 2. `gsub()` does not print to console by default. You need to call `print` explicitly (or) do `{gsub(" ","_")}1`

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) btw; you just want `basename "$old_file" | awk ...` or better yet `basename=${old_file##*/}; basename=$(basename//_/}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually no need of `awk`, please note below one replaces all `space` to `underscore`, not just filename, it can be path too

```
$ old_file="/home/somedir/otherdir/foobar 20170919.csv"
$ newfile="${old_file// /_}"
$ echo "$newfile"
/home/somedir/otherdir/foobar_20170919.csv
```

Comment: It works fine! Thank you. I want to use file name, so I edited the command a little like `new_file=$(basename "${old_file// /_}")`

Comment: @RohanKishibe you are welcome, use can use this, input will be file with path, and  variable new_file will have just filename with underscore `file=${file_with_path##*/}; new_file="${file// /_}"`

Comment: @RohanKishibe: example : `file_with_path="asa/tasas asas/tetst/mayas asas.txt"; file=${file_with_path##*/}; new_file="${file// /_}"; echo "$new_file"`

Comment: There is much to learn... anyway, thank you for good examples!

Comment: @EdMorton thank you, though added in comment missed in answer, fixed now :)